# Alternative to "AsyncRetryPolicy" type in older Polly packages

Tags: c#, polly

I have created a new code/project that uses Polly for Email Retries, and I choose the latest Polly Nuget package v7.2.1.
But then it appeared that we have other projects that use older version of Polly (v2.2.7) and thus I have downgrade package for my project.

But after downgrade it's failing to compile due to this type is not recognized anymore - "AsyncRetryPolicy".

What alternative to this type can I use with older version of Polly?

My code:

```
private AsyncRetryPolicy<Response> CreatePollyPolicy(SendEmailMessageRequest request)
        {
            var policy = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
                .OrResult<SendGrid.Response>(response => 500)
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10 * retryAttempt),
                async (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
                     {
                         await LogFailMessage(request);
                     }
                 );

            return policy;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Polly v2.2.7, the policy type returned by .`WaitAndRetryAsync(...)` is *probably* `RetryPolicy<Response>`.

In many development environments, if you hover your mouse over either the `var` keyword or the `WaitAndRetryAsync(...)` - or if you check the intellisense for the return type from `WaitAndRetryAsync(...)` -  it will tell you what the type is.

**However**, policies handling results (the `.OrResult<TResult>(...)` clause) was not added until [v4.3.0](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430), so you will not be able to use the policy in the question as-is, with v2.2.7.  Recommended would be to upgrade the projects which use v2.2.7 to a later (/the latest) version of Polly, if you can.

Comment: Thanks @mountain traveller. It also cannot recognize '.OnResult<>'. Do you know what I can replace this one with as well?

Comment: Thanks @mountain traveller. So I guess no alternatives for this part, in the older version. I needed this part to explicitly target the specific StatusCode returned.